# Query and update JSON within Python

Tags: python, json

I need to be able to dynamically query a JSON object and then update or append it with values. Note the standard json package is not suitable for the task given the need to query and update an arbitrary set of values. I've found the following packages which support querying a JSON:

1. [JsonPath_rw](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw)
2. [objectpath](http://objectpath.org)
3. [jmespath](http://jmespath.org)

However appear to only support querying the data (please correct if I'm misunderstanding!), not updating or appending. For example, given the following JSON:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 101,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I wanted to append a new 'general' field nested under 'people' and update the id value to 'identifier' from 'id' how could I achieve this in Python using a query framework, such that it looks like:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "identifier": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
    {
      "general": {
        "identifier": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "identifier": 101,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "identifier": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "append a new 'general' field nested under 'people'"? What does your desired result look like?

Comment: @Kevin Sure, updated for you

Comment: Have you read the shown links and tried the tools? They seem to have different use cases, but are all targeted at *querying*. It have not spent much time on them, but enough to understand that the first one is a plain Python package that can give you a value from a JSONPath, and also the real path that you can then use to update or add values. **What have you tried to do without being able to**? Without that information the question is just unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON (as the name implies) is a way to *represent* a JavaScript Object.  To do manipulation, the most appropriate thing would be to parse that representation into an *actual* object, manipulate that, then (if need be) create a new JSON representation of that updated object.  (In fact, I would guess that these query packages do just that, possibly on just enough of the object to satisfy the query.)

Comment: Thanks Scott. I understand that, but for my use case I need to be able to query against the JSON and then update values - the JSON is likely to change in structure therefore I can't determine the structure of the object - hope this makes sense?

Comment: @James Maybe it would help if you explained in your question a bit more thoroughly what you mean by "querying against the JSON". As Scott said, JSON is just a serialization format. How are you actually fetching the JSON and what exactly do you need to do with it once you have it?

Comment: Thanks @glibdud - I'll give it a go, hope this is clear. I am expecting to modify a set of JSONs where the structure is likely to change. The broad format will remain - i.e. in my example 'People' header, however the nested structures will be changing frequently - i.e. in my example 'general'. Therefore to deal with this I'd like to be able to query the JSON structure and then edit/append values instead of relying on a Python object - as the JSON itself is likely to change. Does this make sense?

Comment: @James: If you can read the JSON, you know the structure, so, no, it does not make sense, at least given what you have described of the situation.  Why can't you 1) read the JSON, 2) parse it into an object, 3) manipulate the object as necessary, 4) save the JSON representation of the updated object.

Comment: Apologies. So yes I could build an object for the JSON, but every time the JSON is modified and I need to ingest it again, I'd need to write a whole new object. The second issue is it may change in structure, so if I request the JSON a number of times, I can't guarantee they will be the same each time.

Comment: @James: Why is requesting/writing the object each time a problem?  Seems appropriate for something that changes a lot (as you suggest is the case).

Comment: Think I got myself confused! Thanks for your help Scott :)

Answer (score 1):

As Scott indicates, the object you've got there is not strictly speaking "a JSON object". It's a perfectly ordinary Python dict containing a perfectly ordinary list which contains perfectly ordinary dicts, so you can manipulate it using ordinary iteration/indexed assignment/etc, no frameworks required.

```
d = {
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 101,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
  ]
}

#add new person
d["people"].insert(0, {
    "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20,
    },
    "history": {}
})

#copy `id` over to `identifier` for each person,
#and delete `id`
for person in d["people"]:
    person["general"]["identifier"] = person["general"]["id"]
    del person["general"]["id"]

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'people': [{'general': {'age': 20, 'identifier': 100}, 'history': {}}, {'general': {'age': 20, 'identifier': 100}, 'history': {}}, {'general': {'age': 30, 'identifier': 101}, 'history': {}}, {'general': {'age': 30, 'identifier': 100}, 'history': {}}]}
```

Adding whitespace, you get

```
{
    'people': [
        {
            'general': {
                'age': 20, 
                'identifier': 100
            }, 
            'history': {}
        }, 
        {
            'general': {
                'age': 20, 
                'identifier': 100
            }, 
            'history': {}
        }, 
        {
            'general': {
                'age': 30, 
                'identifier': 101
            }, 
            'history': {}
        }, 
        {
            'general': {
                'age': 30, 
                'identifier': 100
            }, 
            'history': {}
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Of course, this approach only works if you know the structure of the object. If the person sending you this data is allowed to change the structure whenever they want, then your code is very likely to break right away.

I think what you're hoping for is some kind of "smart parser" that can interpret an object with arbitrary structure and understand the conceptual meaning of each component. As far as I know, no such library exists, because it would need human-level intelligence (or better) to make effective guesses for anything other than simple cases.

...That said, you might be able to handle *some* level of changing structure as long as you can make certain guarantees about the data. Let's say that there will always be a "people" key that you want to append to, and there will always be an "id" key that you want to rename. If these facts stay constant, then you can walk through the dict and find the objects you need no matter where they are.

```
import copy

def find_key_item_pairs(obj, criteria):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key_and_value in obj.items():
            if criteria(key_and_value):
                yield key_and_value
            else:
                value = key_and_value[1]
                yield from find_key_item_pairs(value, criteria)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            yield from find_key_item_pairs(item, criteria)

d = {
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 101,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
  ]
}

#dynamically locate all people lists
for _, people_list in find_key_item_pairs(d, lambda kv: kv[0] == "people" and isinstance(kv[1], list)):
    #duplicate the first entry and insert
    people_list.insert(0, copy.deepcopy(people_list[0]))

#dynamically locate all dicts containing "id"
for _, person in find_key_item_pairs(d, lambda kv: isinstance(kv[1], dict) and "id" in kv[1]):
    #swap out "id" for "identifier"
    person["identifier"] = person["id"]
    del person["id"]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's read in the structure:

```
dictPeople = {
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 101,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's a Python dictionary.

1.To add a new object under `people`, we use standard Python's dictionary functionality. No JSON querying is needed:

```
dictAdd = {
      "general": {
        "identifier": 100,
        "age": 30
      },
      "history": {
      }
    }
dictPeople['people'].append(dictAdd)
```

2.To update the field name which is in an **unknown place** in the structure, we can first use JSON querying (JSONPath) to localize it, using one of the libraries e.g. [jsonpath-ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng). After we get the smallest structure (a dictionary) with that field, we can update it using standard dictionary functionality of updating the key. After that, we apply the updated dictionary back to the JSON structure. The code is as follows:

```
import json 
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

# localize the fields to update based on JSONPath query
jsExp = parse("$..people[?general.id].general")
match = jsExp.find(dictPeople)
for obj in match:
    print(obj.value)
    # get the smallest structure with the field
    dictGeneral = obj.value # the structure is a dictionary
    # update the field
    dictGeneral['identifier'] = dictGeneral['id']
    del dictGeneral['id']
    # update JSON structure
    jsExp.update(dictPeople,dictGeneral)

print(dictPeople)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I think you may find  [glom](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) useful and more pythonic, besides you can still use `jmespath` to complement different uses.